# Facebook post extraction using Javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to make an application that will help me in extracting the posts of the users, and even their email using the Facebook Login API. I tried the following but could not rectify where exactly from I can extract the text post and use it for my purpose of NLP experiment.

See the following code:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
        <!-- Facebook Login Function -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=APP-ID";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
  }
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
});
    }
    </script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

I just want to pass the posts to a function where I can move further and make the NLP process work for it.

Here is the function that works as NLP process:

```
<script>

//Validation for Paste Text field   
    function validate()
{
    console.log( "Inside validate");
    //return false;
     var obj1 = document.getElementById('for_analysis').value;
     console.log("Pring value of text area")
      console.log( obj1);

         if(obj1.trim() == '') 
         {      
            console.log( "Empty space found");
              alert("Please Enter some Text before submitting");
              //obj1.focus();
              return false;       
         }
         else{
         console.log( "No empty space found");
          $(".trial").show();
         //document.getElementById("chkjq").className = "chkjq";
           return true;
        }
}
    //paste this code under head tag or in a seperate js file.
    // Wait for window load
    $(document).ready(function(){
console.log( "inside jquery");
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        console.log( "Page Loading");
        //$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
        //$(".trial").fadeOut("slow");;
        //$("#download").remove();
    });

     $(".chkjq").click(function(){
        //console.log( "Hello, world!");
       //$(".trial").show();
    });
    $("#filebutton").click(function(){
        //console.log( "Hello, world! file button");
       $(".trial").show();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

The above function is applied to a textarea from where I am getting the text and processing it. :

```
<form action ="/analyze/" method="POST" name ="sendtext" id="sendtext"  onsubmit="javascript:return validate()" >
            {% csrf_token %}
         <textarea  id ="for_analysis"  name ="for_analysis" form="sendtext" style="background-color: lightgrey"></textarea> 
        <!-- <input id="for_analysis" type="textarea" name="for_analysis" > -->
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="box__button chkjq" id = "chkjq">UPLOAD</button> 
        <!--<button id="ana_text">Analyze</button> -->
        <br/></form>
```

Now I want to perform the same by extracting text post from the FB. Kindly let me know what I can do to make it right?

Comment: what exactly is the issue? i am not sure what your question is, to be honest. if you want to extract text from facebook, just use the api to get the posts. where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck in the usage of the API .... As you can see in the bove code I tried to get the application work but could not see what I have to do to extract the text and use it with the function of NLP `validate()`, so that I can process the posts.

Comment: i only see an api call to /me, that will only return basic user info. also, there is no login callback in your login button, and you are using FB.getLoginStatus 2 times - you should only use it on page load, with the async callback...a lot of stuff is missing there, you should hit the docs and check out basic implementation of the js sdk.

Comment: this may also help you, read the whole article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Yes your link is helpful... I already have check it. But the problem is again I am not able to understand how to extract the posts?

Comment: did you check out the api reference already?

Comment: Actually through your stackoverflow profile I check your website and got the link you referred in your comment. I have tried it to check if I can get the posts by call `/me` but what I get is only the name or id which looks default.

Comment: you need to ask for fields you want to get...it´s called "declarative fields".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example - with `FB.login` instead of the login button:

```
const getPosts = () => {
    FB.api('/me/posts', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
};

const getEmail = () => {
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
};

FB.login((response) => {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
        getPosts();
        getEmail();
    }
}, {scope: 'email,user_posts'});
```

Additional info: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Btw, you can also combine the API calls:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,posts'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: btw, you should really read this, it explains a lot of important stuff: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api